# What is the priority list to determine in which order clinical bacterial samples should be processed for microbiological research purposes?

Tags: bacteria, microbiology

### *Background*

Sample processing is an essential step in clinical bacteriology that involves the proper handling and treatment of clinical samples before they can be subjected to further analysis and testing.

Sample processing in clinical bacteriology involves several key steps. These include:

- Smear preparation
- Inoculation onto culture media
- Incubation

Clinical samples in bacteriology have different types. For example, a sample could be one of the following types:

- Lower respiratory tract samples

  - Non-invasive

    - Sputum
  - Invasive

    - Tracheal aspirate
    - Endotracheal aspirate (ETA)
    - Endotracheal tube (ETT)
    - Bronchoalveolar lavage (BAL)
    - Bronchial washings (BW)
- Wound/Abscess
- Catheter tips samples
- Urine samples
- Sterile body fluids samples

  - Blood
  - Cerebrospinal fluid (CSF)
  - Pleural fluid
  - Ascitic fluid (intraperitoneal fluid)

In any laboratory, it is common for multiple clinical samples of different types to arrive simultaneously. As a result, if batch processing is not available, it becomes necessary to establish a priority order for processing these samples.

The clinical pathology laboratory is concerned with the diagnosis of pathogens for the sake of the patient. In the clinical pathology laboratory, this order is based on the clinical significance of a certain sample type if it was positive for a pathogen:

> When multiple specimens arrive at the same time, priority should be
> given to those that are most critical, such as cerebrospinal fluid
> (CSF), tissue, blood, and sterile fluids. (Bailey & Scott's Diagnostic Microbiology, 13th edition.)

The microbiological laboratory, on the other hand, is concerned with the organisms in the clinical sample.
In the microbiological laboratory, this order should be based on the effect of the delay of sample processing on the ability to culture and isolate pathogens.

### *Question*

What is the priority list to determine in which order clinical bacterial samples should be processed for microbiological research purposes, as in prevalence studies for example? If possible, I want the answer to include the priority list of the sample types in the background part of this question.

For more specificity, the research objective is the isolation of *Acinetobacter* (Gram-negative aerobic bacteria) for these sample types.

### *Prior Research*

All the textbooks I have seen focus on the perspective of the clinical pathological laboratory, even the microbiological textbooks.

Comment: I don't really see how there could possibly be such a list, wouldn't it depend on the research question(s)? For what purposes are you looking for this information?

Comment: When i wrote this, i probably wanted general information, but now I think it would be better if I narrowed it down. thanks.

Comment: I want to isolate acinetobacter from clinical samples.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What research question are you trying to address?

Comment: Species identification of Acinetobacter isolates obtained from clinical samples in a critical care setting.

Comment: That's not a research question.

Comment: What are the types of Acinetobacter species that can be isolated from all the clinical samples of patients in X intensive care unit in Y hospital?

(Prevalence study)

Comment: Then why is there a priority? If you want to isolate from all samples, you need to process all samples.

Comment: What if i don't have enough resources & man power to process all samples simultaneously?

Comment: Then you should reconsider your research question.

Comment: Oh wait i think you misunderstood me, what i mean by priority is the order for processing: which sample type can wait and which can't.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would matter but maybe I'm missing something.